# How do I tell a running Dyalog session to accept RIDE connections?

Tags: connection, listener, apl, dyalog, dyalog-ride

Dyalog RIDE can connect to running interpreter sessions, but in order for that to work, is there a way to tell an already running session that it should start listening to incoming connections?

I know I can start a *new* session with the following environment variable set:

```
RIDE_INIT="serve::4502"
```

and it'll listen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to accomplishing this. Since the interpreter wasn't started with `RIDE_INIT="serve::4502"`, we need to set this initialisation string. After that, we'll need to actually start listening for an incoming connection. Both of these are accomplished using the `3502⌶` function (called *Manage RIDE Connections*):

```
3502⌶'serve::4502'  ⍝ set initialisation string
3502⌶1              ⍝ start listening
```

We can combine both into a single step by mapping the function over an array of these two values:

```
3502⌶¨'serve::4502' 1
```